# How to perform form validation on HTML form using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I need to verify data has been entered into the required HTML form fields using JavaScript as a validation method.

Please see current code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

<form id="myForm" name="myForm">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Your Information Please:</legend>
    <input type="text" name="Your_Name" placeholder="First Name"><br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name"><br>
    <input type="email" size="32" maxLength="32" required pattern=".+@apus.com" placeholder="APUS Email" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Please choose your favorite subject:</legend>
        <select name="subjects">
        <option>Math</option>
        <option>Science</option>
        <option>History</option>
        <option>English</option>
        <option>Art</option>
        </select><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Data" onclick="return checkForm(this.form);" />
    </fieldset>
</form>

<script>
function checkName()
{
    if(document.getElementById('myForm').value === "")
    alert("Enter something");
    return false;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The expected result should be that a dialog box appears if no name is entered that says "Please enter your first name."

If the last name is not entered but the first name is entered "Please enter your last name."

If both the first and last name have already been inputted an email should be required. I've taken care of this part though using the HTML "required pattern" attribute.

Comment: Please edit your attempt at the logic you're looking for into your question. At the moment there doesn't seem to be any.

Comment: Voting to close because the problem is caused by a typo. You typed the wrong ID. You're reading the `value` of the `<form>` and not the first name `<input>` (which needs an ID).

Comment: [The placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: `<fieldset>` is designed for a *set* of fields, not a single field. Your second `<legend>` should be the `<select>`'s `<label>`.

Comment: Removing the fieldset, and changing my code around a bit seems to have solved my issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rami I like your answer, but I did manage to figure this out myself based on a few of the comments.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

<form id="myForm" name="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name"><br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name"><br>
    <input type="email" name="email" size="32" maxLength="32" required pattern=".+@apus.com" placeholder="APUS Email" />
    <br><br>
    Please choose your favorite subject:
    <br>
        <select name="subjects">
        <option>Math</option>
        <option>Science</option>
        <option>History</option>
        <option>English</option>
        <option>Art</option>
        </select><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Data" onclick="return checkForm(this.form);" />
</form>

<script>
    function checkForm()
    {
        var str = '';
        var elem = document.getElementById('myForm').elements;
        for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++)
        {
           if(elem[i].value.length < 1)
{
alert("Enter something for the field: " + elem[i].name);
var mytext = document.getElementById(elem[i].name); 
    mytext.focus();
return false;}
        } 
     }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, If you are validating any kind of input you have to make sure that you also validate it on the server-side and not only client-side validation. Client-side validation is just for UX and can be easily escaped.

In your case, the below will work:

Give an "id" for each input field:

```
<input id="txtfname" type="text" name="Your_Name" placeholder="First Name">
<input id="txtlname" type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">

<script>
function checkName()
{
    if(document.getElementById('txtfname').value == ""){
        alert("Enter first name");
        return false;
    } else if (document.getElementById('txtfname').value <> "" && document.getElementById('txtlname').value == ""){
        alert("Enter last name");
        return false;
    }
    else{
    return true
    }
}
</script>
```